# svn diff through perltidy

Tags: perl, svn, perl-tidy

I want to run perltidy before i look for diff in my subversion working copy.
in svn config i wrote:

```
diff-cmd = /usr/bin/d.sh
```

As David W said in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5834900/1927848 i make a script /usr/bin/d.sh:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/perltidy "$1" > "/tmp/$1"
/usr/local/bin/perltidy "$2" > "/tmp/$2"
/usr/bin/diff "$1" "$2"
/bin/rm "/tmp/$1" "/tmp/$2"
exit 0
```

and when i make svn diff in working copy i got some errors:

```
dev# svn diff
Index: nodeny/new_month.pl
===================================================================
Unknown option: u
Error on command line; for help try 'perltidy -h'
Option l is ambiguous (libpods, line-up-parentheses, logfile, logfile-gap, long-block-line-count, look-for-autoloader, look-for-hash-bang, look-for-selfloader)
Error on command line; for help try 'perltidy -h'
diff: option requires an argument -- L
/usr/bin/diff: Try `/usr/bin/diff --help' for more information.
```

where is my errors?

UPD: $1 and $2 are not file names, $6 and $7 contains file names. i made some modifications to code, thanks to ikegami [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581782/svn-diff-through-perltidy#comment23829218_16581782)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/perltidy "$6" -st > "/tmp/tidy001"
/usr/local/bin/perltidy "$7" -st > "/tmp/tidy002"
/usr/bin/diff "/tmp/tidy001" "/tmp/tidy002"
/bin/rm "/tmp/tidy001" "/tmp/tidy002"
exit 0
```

but now script only does first perltidy command and wait... whats wrong?

UPD2: perl script, that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Text::Diff;

if (-e $ARGV[-2] && -e $ARGV[-1]) {
    my $str1 = `/usr/local/bin/perltidy -npro -pbp -nst -se -et=4 -bar -l=200 $ARGV[-2] -st`;
    my $str2 = `/usr/local/bin/perltidy -npro -pbp -nst -se -et=4 -bar -l=200 $ARGV[-1] -st`;
    my $diff = diff(\$str1, \$str2);
    print $diff;
}
else {
    print "Error file $ARGV[-2] or $ARGV[-1] not exists\n";
}
exit 0;
```

Comment: You simply need more robust argument handling. Looks like (at least) `-u` and `-l` are passed to the script in addition to the file names.

Comment: @ikegami, thanks, updated my question. got other problem:(

Comment: Is either of the file names `-` or something that starts with `-`?

Comment: svn file name `/tmp/tru/.svn/pristine/0d/0de49951070d7da521e9b26cde1853e6b66a665a.svn-base` contains `-`. but it doesnt matter already. i hate bash. i rewrote this script in perl, and it works fine. a love perl, thanks for your help

Comment: ug, you went back to fragile hard-coded arg nums and to using temporary files. You already got bitten by the former once, maybe even twice!

Comment: i'll try to fix it now, thanks for critics

Comment: `/usr/bin/diff "$args[@]" \
   <( /usr/local/bin/perltidy "$f1" -st ) \
   <( /usr/local/bin/perltidy "$f2" -st )` does this command will work in perl?

Comment: huh? no. `/usr/` will look like a regex match, which Perl would expect to be followed by an operator, but `bin` is not an operator. (`Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at -e line 1.
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "/usr/bin"
        (Missing operator before bin?)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an experienced `bash` code, so the following may not be optimal, especially given the redundancy, but it solves your problem by assuming the last two args are the file names.

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("$@")

f1_idx=$(( ${#args[@]} - 2 ))
f1="${args[$f1_idx]}"
/usr/local/bin/perltidy "$f1" -st > "/tmp/$f1"
args[$f1_idx]="/tmp/$f1"

f2_idx=$(( ${#args[@]} - 1 ))
f2="${args[$f2_idx]}"
/usr/local/bin/perltidy "$f2" -st > "/tmp/$f2"
args[$f2_idx]="/tmp/$f2"

/usr/bin/diff "$args[@]"
/bin/rm "/tmp/$f1" "/tmp/$f2"

exit 0
```

Or if you don't care about the actual file names (as your update implies), you can avoid the temporary files altogether.

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("$@")

last_idx=$(( ${#args[@]} - 1 ))
f2="${args[$last_idx]}"
unset args[$last_idx]

last_idx=$(( ${#args[@]} - 1 ))
f1="${args[$last_idx]}"
unset args[$last_idx]

/usr/bin/diff "$args[@]" \
   <( /usr/local/bin/perltidy "$f1" -st ) \
   <( /usr/local/bin/perltidy "$f2" -st )

exit 0
```